# Two problems when redirecting after login

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using the `FOSUserBundle` on a *symfony2* project. The user can log in and logout and everything works just fine.

The "backend route" is like:

```
/backend
```

Which redirects to:

```
/backend/login
```

**First problem:**

If the user calls the login page directly:

```
/backend/login
```

he gets redirected to the startpage and not to `/backend` after a successfull login.

**Second problem:**

The user is redirected to a URL where the credentials are checked:

```
/backend/login_check
```

Some browsers save this URL, so it gets into autocompletion and the user doesn't recorgnize that he is calling `backend/login_check` as it redirects to `login`. However, the problem is, that after a successfull login, *symfony2* tries to redirect the user to the route `check_login` which fails and most of the time results in showing the login window again.

**security.yml**

```
firewalls:
    login_firewall:
        pattern:    ^/backend/login$
        anonymous:  ~

    backend:
        pattern:    ^/backend
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: /backend/login
            check_path: /backend/login_check
            #use_forward: true
```

**routing.yml**

```
login:
    pattern:   /backend/login
    defaults:  { _controller: VendorNameBundle:User:login }
login_check:
    pattern:   /backend/login_check
```

How can I solve those two issues?

Answer (score 0):

First, remove your `login_firewall`. You don't need it. Instead, use `access_control` as described [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-4-configure-your-applications-securityyml)

Then, you can use the `default_target_path` option for your `backend` firewall :

```
backend:
    pattern:    ^/backend
    form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        login_path: /backend/login
        check_path: /backend/login_check
        default_target_path: /backend
```

See more [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#changing-the-default-page)